# Canonical term for "simultaneous data-latching"

Tags: buffer, naming-conventions, fpga, dataflow, doublebuffered

I have a module (in my case on an FPGA) where several input values (registers) are updated sequentially (if at all), but are all copied in parallel in a single, atomic step to guarantee coherency during the following data processing steps. 
Is there a common term for this?

- "*Double-Buffering*" comes close, but usually refers to two buffers in parallel that are swapped, while I'm actually copying them "forward".
- "*Simultaneous data-latching*" is what I'm using at the moment, but it sounds unfamiliar...

**Illustration**

```
               store_1             store_all             do_stuff
                  |                    |                     |                               
                +-+-+                +-+-+                 +-+-+                                       
   value_1 -->  |Reg| --- int_1 -->  |Reg| --> input_1 --> | M |                                                          
                +---+                +---+                 | o |                                    
                                       |                   | d |
               store_2                 |                   | u | --> outputs                             
                  |                    |                   | l |                                
                +-+-+                +-+-+                 | e |                                    
   value_2 -->  |Reg| --- int_2 -->  |Reg| --> input_2 --> |   |                                                           
                +---+                +---+                 +---+                                   

                 __  ____________________
    value_1      __><____________________       


    store_1      ______|_________________                                                                                       

                 _______  _______________
    input_1      _______><_______________


                 __________  ____________
    value_2      __________><____________                                                                                     


    store_2      ______________|_________                                               

                 _______________  _______
    input_2      _______________><_______



    store_all    ____________________|___

                 _____________________  _
    out_1        _____________________><_

                 _____________________  _
    out_2        _____________________><_


    do_stuff     _______________________|
```

Here `store_1`, `store_2` and `store_all` are write-enable signals for their registers, are synchronously clocked with the same clock.

Comment: I would generally refer to that as "Output latching", which is (for me) the step that register a module's outputs and declare them as valid.

Comment: I don't like using the term "latch" for things that aren't true latches. I would consider naming them "alignment registers".

Answer (score 1):

Looks like basic shift-registers to me.

This type of arrangement might be called *retiming registers* if there presence is purely to help ease the routing pressure to 'Module'. Or perhaps *pipelining registers* if they are inserted to maintain some specific alignment between 'value_1/value_2' and 'outputs', say if the latency through Module changed at some point.

If control signals store_1 / store_2 /store_all are infact clocks, they may be called *synchronisation stages*, although the design has problems in this case.

Your question mixes words that are tangentially related to digital logic timing, without being specific.

Comment: Well, technically they are two-stage shift-registers, but I'm looking for a word that focusses on the simultaneous copy intended to keep the data consistent while a processing is ongoing, during which new data can already arrive. I've updated the question to underline that there's only one clock-domain, `store_*` are merely clock- or write-enable signals.

Comment: still sounds like a shift register